# Java - Difference between Java 8 parallelStream and creating threads ourselves

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-8, runnable

I was trying to find the difference between using Java 8's `parallelStream`(method1) and creating parallel threads(method2)

I measured the time taken when using method 1 and method 2. But I found a huge deviation.  Method2(~700ms) is way faster than method1(~20sec)

**Method 1:** (list has about 100 entries)

```
list.parallelStream()
    .forEach(ele -> {
        //Do something.
    }));
```

**Method 2:**

```
for(i = 0;i < 100; i++) {
    Runnable task = () -> {
     //Do something.
    }
    Thread thread = new Thread(task);
    thread.start();
}
```

**NOTE:** Do something is an expensive operation like hitting a Database.

I added System.out.println() messages to both. I found that method 1(parallelStream) *appeared* to be executing sequentially while in method 2 the messages were printed very fast.

Can anyone explain what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone explain what is happening.

Most likely you are doing something wrong but it's not clear what.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    IntStream.range(0, 100).parallel()
            .forEach(ele -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                }
            });
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    System.out.printf("Took %,d ms to perform 100 tasks of 100 ms on %d processors%n",
            time, Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
}
```

prints

```
Took 475 ms to perform 100 tasks of 100 ms on 32 processors
Took 401 ms to perform 100 tasks of 100 ms on 32 processors
Took 401 ms to perform 100 tasks of 100 ms on 32 processors
```

Comment: If we have say 4 cores, is it possible to have more than 4 threads running parallely

Comment: @user7 you can but you have to set `-Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=` however this won't be optimal for any CPU bound tasks.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html

Comment: So when using parallelStream of java8, one thread won't be created for each iteration of the loop right? But when using method2 we force such a behaviour?

Comment: And when using method1, we can predict the order in which it executes. i.e statement outside the `list.parallelStream` won't be executed before the iteration is over. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @user7 you are right in both cases.  You can use an ExecutorService instead of creating lots of threads. This will allow you to re-use threads and control the size of the pool as well and check on the progress of individual tasks.

Comment: When I print `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`, it prints 2. So it means only two threads were executing in parallel at a time. Is it right? If so, it must be the reason that it seemed like serial execution

Comment: @user7 indeed. For CPU bound tasks it usually sense to no more threads than CPUs, however for tasks with a high IO/network latency you can see an advantage in using more threads to wait for multiple requests/queries.